# Cloud Functions Emulator can't get default credentials

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to test my cloud function locally, and using the Functions emulator has been fine until I tried adding Datastore to my project. Now whenever I start the emulator, deploy, and call the function with my test data via `--file=test.json`, i get an error from my datastore promise

`error: (node:35048) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.`

the only problem with this is that i've tried it multiple times, both with beta and normal `auth` modules, ie:

`gcloud beta auth application-default login`

and

`gcloud auth application-default login`

they both say they are successful but my Functions emulator still fails no matter what.

Datastore version ^1.1.0 & Google Cloud SDK 170.0.1, beta 2017.03.24

Comment: It surprises we even need to supply creds for using the emulator

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. a workaround is to set `process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "path to json file";`

However, you cant deploy the function like that, a better solution would be nice.